# Why is the number 30 not displayed at the end of the output?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, intellij-idea, output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqtkK.png)

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        int p=0;

        for (int i=1; i<11; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(p);
                p = p + i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: print is before the add, the final value for p is not printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a print ***after*** the loop. You can also start with `2`. And increment by `2` for each iteration (thus eliminating the need for the modulo two test). Something like,

```
int p = 0;
for (int i = 2; i < 11; i += 2) {
    System.out.println(p);
    p += i;
}
System.out.println(p);
```

Which outputs

```
0
2
6
12
20
30
```